# powershell - search from a file & replace into another file

Tags: powershell

I want to search a collections of strings from a file and replace into another file. For example :

File A.txt (Search patterns)

File B.txt (Acutal file)

So, here I want to replace all strings given in File A to File B (compare/replace all lines of File A with each line of File B). I would like to implement in simple ways, maybe using foreachobject loops. Please help me ??

Comment: You named source of search patterns (file A), and target file (file B), but where is the source of string that you want to replace patterns with? Or do you want to remove those entirely...?

Answer (score 0):

For a good learning experience, I have created a cmdlet below. The inline comments should be able to guide you on how it was done.

```powershell
function Get-ReplacedText
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        # Path containing the text file to be searched.
        $FilePath,

        # Path containing the patterns to be searched and replaced.
        $SearchPatternFilePath
    )

    # Patterns will be read in full for fast access.
    $patterns = Get-Content -Path $SearchPatternFilePath 

    # Use the StreamReader for efficiency.
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($FilePath)

    # Open the file
    while(-not $reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()

        foreach ($pattern in $patterns) {

            $search, $replacement = $pattern.Split()

            # Replace any searched text that exist with replacement.
            $line = $line -replace $search, $replacement
        }

        # Get the replaced line out of the pipeline.
        $line
    }

    #Close the file.
    $reader.Close()
}
```

Take note, the file that you are reading the patterns from should be structured as such, with a space separating the search pattern and the replacement text. Additionally the search pattern can be in Regexp format.

```
searchpattern1 replacement1
searchpattern2 replacement2
```

Finally, an example to use the cmdlet,

```
Get-ReplacedText -FilePath txtfile.txt -SearchPatternFilePath searchpattern.txt | Out-File -FilePath result.txt -Encoding ascii
```